# Value not closed over in a loop, despite function-wrapping

Tags: javascript, closures

I have a list of objects I am looping over; each of these objects has a property on it which is a function referring to `this`.  If I create a list of callbacks based on my objects, it seems that I have to "double-wrap" the `this`-dependent function in order to maintain the correct references.  I don't understand why this is - can anyone explain?

```
function Pokemon(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sayName = function() {
        console.log(this.name);
    };
}

function runFunctions(arrayOfFunctions) {
    for (var i = 0, fn; fn = arrayOfFunctions[i]; i++) {
        fn();
    }
}

var monsters = [
    new Pokemon('Charmander'), 
    new Pokemon('Squirtle'),
    new Pokemon('Bulbasaur')
];

var unclosedCalls = [];
var closedCalls = [];

for (var i = 0, monster; monster = monsters[i]; i++) {
    var unclosedCall = (function(m) {
            return m.sayName
        })(monster);

    var closedCall = (function(m) {
            return function() {
                m.sayName();
            }
        })(monster);

    unclosedCalls.push(unclosedCall);
    closedCalls.push(closedCall);
}

console.log('--start')
runFunctions(unclosedCalls); // doesn't work
console.log('----')
runFunctions(closedCalls); // works
console.log('--end')
```

`closedCalls` is the list of double-wrapped callbacks.

I don't get why `m` in each creation of `unclosedCall` is not actually closed over.

Here is a jsbin with my code: http://jsbin.com/qivilusuje/1/edit?js,console,output

Comment: That's a novel `for` loop termination test...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the "unclosed" calls is that the function reference that you return (`m.sayName`) is immediately disassociated from the variable `m` from which the function property was retrieved.

A function reference doesn't know anything about which object it was retrieved from so therefore when the function is eventually invoked it has no "context" - `this` will be set to the global object instead of the object that originally had this function as a property:

```
var obj = {
    func : function() { console.log(this) }
}

obj.func() // outputs "obj" because a.b() calls "b" with "this" === "a"
var ref = obj.func;
ref();     // outputs "window"
```

To fix it you can have the unclosed call do `return m.sayName.bind(m)`, although having got that far there's no need for the IIFE either, and it would work just as well to say:

```
var unclosedCall = monster.sayName.bind(monster);
```